# How to re-start the Julia kernel in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, julia

I have a VS Code window open with Julia and a Jupyter notebook. I want to re-start the kernel to make sure I am working in a clean environment. However, I do not see a button to do so:

[image: VS Code top bar]

How can I re-start the Julia kernel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the Julia workspace pane instead:

[image]